# Default value doesn't get updated inside input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a list of certain records where I'm populating in the dropdown of an input component. The default value is set on page loading but, I need to update it on click event of a button. Refer to the code below.

Home.js

```
const allList = [
    { id: "1", value: "Fruits" },
    { id: "2", value: "Vegetables" },
    { id: "3", value: "Grains" },
    { id: "4", value: "Milk" },
    { id: "5", value: "Meat" },
    { id: "6", value: "Fish" },
    { id: "7", value: "Pulses" }
  ];

const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(allList);
const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(allList[0].value)

// I want to set the value on click of cancel button
const handleCancel = (e) => {
    setNewValue(allList[2].value)
    setPopup(false);
  };

return (
<>
<DataList
            defaultValue={newValue}
            list="itemListOptions"
            id="itemList"
            placeholder="Search/select items"
            data={itemList}
            onSelectionChange={itemChanged}
          ></DataList>
{popup === true ? (
        <Popup okbtnClick={handleOK} canclebtnclick={handleCancel} />
      ) : null}
</>
)
```

DataList.js

```
        <input
         defaultValue={props?.defaultValue ?? ""}
         className="form-control cpselect"
         id={props?.id ?? ""}
         list={props?.list ?? ""}
         placeholder={props?.placeholder ?? ""}
         onChange={props?.onSelectionChange ?? ""}
        />
        <datalist key={props.id} id={props?.list ?? ""}>
         {props.data.map((d) => {
          return <option key={d.id} id={d.id} value={d.value}></option>;
         })}
        </datalist>
```

My intention is to change the defaultValue inside the input field, on click of cancel button. Here it loads the first element and on click event should load third element. What is the best optimal solution?

Please refer to the Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-rumple-ig0wwj

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use `value` instead of `defaultValue`.

`defaultValue` property is configured in such a way that it reads the prop only once and then creates an inner state that handles changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with value but it doesn't work

Comment: Works fine for me, but the code in your sandbox doesn't much that in the question.

Comment: you can check now. I have reverted all the changes

Comment: Changed `defaultValue` to `value` in `DataList.js` and works fine, although I had to set the popup to `true` initially because I had no idea how to open it.

Comment: but the text doesn't get edited

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-hooks-14usnu please click `cancel`

Comment: even I tried this one but, input text and dropdown doesn't work